# ItemWriter not producing output when having a StepScope annotation to access parameter in ItemReader in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm using a spring boot with spring batch application to test passing a parameter to the `ItemReader` by using below code, but the content of `contact-out.dat` file (which is the output file) is empty when I use `StepScope` annotation. There's no error, it just doesn't produce any result:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemReader<Contact> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}") String fileName) {             
    
    BeanIOFlatFileItemReader<Contact> reader = new BeanIOFlatFileItemReader<>();
    try {           
        reader.setUseSpringExceptions(true);
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(fileName));
        reader.setStreamName(inputContactStreamName);
        reader.setStreamMapping(new ClassPathResource(beanIoConfigurationXmlPath));
        reader.setStreamFactory(StreamFactory.newInstance());
        reader.getLineNumber();
        reader.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("ERROR: An issue occurred in the BeanIO Item Reader:: {} {}", e.getMessage(), e.getStackTrace());
    }
    
    return reader;      
    
}    

@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<Contact> writer() {
    
    FlatFileItemWriter<Contact> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
    writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(fileOutputContact));
    writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<Contact>() {
        {
            setDelimiter(",");
            setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Contact>() {
                {
                    setNames(new String[] { "firstName", "lastName", "street", "city", "state", "zip" });
                }                   
            });
        }
    });
    
    return writer;
}
    
@Bean("InputJob")
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public Job importUserJob(Step step) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
      .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())          
      .flow(step)
      .end()
      .build();
}

@Bean
public Step step(ItemReader<Contact> reader) {      
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
      .<Contact, Contact> chunk(10)
      .reader(reader(null))          
      .processor(contactItemProcessor)
      .writer(writer())          
      .build();
}
```

Now, if I remove the `StepScope` annotation and make below changes then `contact-out.dat` file has the expected content:

```
@Bean
//@StepScope
public ItemReader<Contact> reader(/*@Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}") String fileName*/) {...}


@Bean
public Step step(ItemReader<Contact> reader) {      
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
      .<Contact, Contact> chunk(10)
      .reader(reader(/*null*/))          
      .processor(contactItemProcessor)
      .writer(writer())          
      .build();
}
```

What I'm doing wrong here when using `StepScope` annotation that ouput file is always empty?

Comment: You are already injecting the reader into the method that procudes the stepp.. Why call `reader(null)` then? Just use the passed in argument. Another thing is don't catch the exceptions in the `@Bean` method and don't call `afterPropertiesSet` those are framework callbacks and hinder proper container management and might even hide a problem you actually have. Finally change the return type from `ItemReader<Contact>` to `BeanIOFlatFileItemReader<Contact>` (you want to do tha tfor the writer as well) be as specific as you can so all callbacks etc. can be detected.

Comment: @M.Deinum changing the return type from `ItemReader<Contact>` to `BeanIOFlatFileItemReader<Contact>` did the trick. I've also implemented your other suggestions :) Please post an answer to give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `@Configuration` classes the best thing to do for `@Bean` methods is to be as specific as possible about the type. As this type information is used at load time to determine what callbacks to do or what proxy to create.

When you are adding an `@StepScope` what happens is that a lazy proxy is created for the argument type of the method. In your case that is an `ItemReader<Contact>`. If you check the [javadoc of the `FlatFileItemReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReader.html) you see that it implements more interfaces. Those interfaces are needed by Spring Batch to do the appropriate callbacks to initialize the reader. However if it is an `ItemReader` those callbacks aren't there.

```java
@Bean
@StepScope
public BeanIOFlatFileItemReader<Contact> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}") String fileName) {             
    BeanIOFlatFileItemReader<Contact> reader = new BeanIOFlatFileItemReader<>();
    reader.setUseSpringExceptions(true);
    reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(fileName));
    reader.setStreamName(inputContactStreamName);
    reader.setStreamMapping(new ClassPathResource(beanIoConfigurationXmlPath));
    reader.setStreamFactory(StreamFactory.newInstance());
    reader.getLineNumber();
    return reader;          
}
```

With this the proper proxy will be created and all the callbacks will be effective.

In your configuration you are already injecting the `ItemReader` as an argument use that instead of calling `reader(null)`.

```java
@Bean
public Step step(BeanIOFlatFileItemReader<Contact> reader) {      
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
      .<Contact, Contact> chunk(10)
      .reader(reader)          
      .processor(contactItemProcessor)
      .writer(writer())          
      .build();
}
```